# Use a where condition on a datetime field of an associated entity with Doctrine2?

Tags: php, sql, join, doctrine-orm, dql

I basically have a Chat entity which is linked by a ManyToOne associatino to an event. So One chat can only refer to one event but one event can have multiple chats.
Each event have a dateEnd which specify at which date does the event ends.

Basically:

```
class Chat
{
    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many Requests are associated to one Event (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Event", inversedBy="invitations")
     */
    private $event;
}
```

and in my event:

```
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_end", type="datetime", nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
     private $dateEnd;


     /**
     * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="event", cascade={"remove"})
     */
     private $invitations;
}
```

I am trying to grab the events that have not ended yet.
But I can't have it working:

This works :

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select( 'CHATS', 'messages' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Chat',  'CHATS' )
        ->where( 'CHATS.user = :user' )
        ->leftJoin( 'CHATS.messages', 'messages' )
        ->orderBy( 'CHATS.lastActive', 'DESC' );

    $array = array(
         'user' => $user
    );

    $qb->setParameters( $array );

    $newMessages = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select( 'CHATS', 'messages' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Chat',  'CHATS' )
        ->where( 'CHATS.user = :user' )
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->gt( 'CHATS.event.dateEnd', ':yesterday' )
        )
        ->leftJoin( 'CHATS.messages', 'messages' )
        ->orderBy( 'CHATS.lastActive', 'DESC' );


    //Only take notifs that end after the beggining of the day ..
    $yesterday = new \DateTime( 'NOW', new \DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') );

    $array = array(
         'yesterday' => $yesterday,
         'user' => $user
    );

    $qb->setParameters( $array );

    $newMessages = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So Doctrine doesn't like the

`->andWhere(
                $qb->expr()->gt( 'CHATS.event.dateEnd', ':yesterday' )
            )`

Why ?

Many Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Add CHATS.event in a join (leftJoin('CHATS.event', 'event'), then you can use event.dateEnd in the where condition

Comment: that was it.
Why is it acting this way ?

Comment: Your first query just returns chats.  When you call $chat->getEvent() a second query is kicked off behind the scenes to lazy load the event.  So it may seem like event is automatically linked to chat but it is not.  In your second query, Doctrine 2 is not quite smart enough to handle CHATS.event.dateEnd.  Hence the need for an explicit join so the where clause can work.

Comment: thanks, you hsould write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query just returns chats. When you call $chat->getEvent() a second query is kicked off behind the scenes to lazy load the event. So it may seem like event is automatically linked to chat but it is not.

In your second query, Doctrine 2 is not quite smart enough to handle CHATS.event.dateEnd. Hence the need for an explicit event join so the where clause can work.